# r shiny: highlight some cells

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

In shiny, I use plotOutput to output a table, and I want to highlight some cells of it according to some criteria. 
Is there any functions in shiny that could achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

======================

Besides to highlighting, I'd also like to add radio buttons on the left of the table, so I could know which lines user chose. Now I'm using renderDataTable to do this, however it doesn't seem to have the highlighting function.
Could it be possible?

Comment: Hello, I didn't try with radio buttons but it work well with check box ! I edited my answer to show an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello a solution without `ggplot2` but with package `ReporteRs`, see the app below for example, the main function is `FlexTable` :

**EDIT :** yes, you can put shiny widgets into the HTML table, here an example with `checkboxInput` for selecting rows :

```
library(ReporteRs)
library(shiny)
mtcars = mtcars[1:6, ]
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel = headerPanel("FlexTable"),
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "colCol", label = "Col to color", choices = c("None",     colnames(mtcars)), selected = "None"),
      selectizeInput(inputId = "rowCol", label = "Row to color", choices = rownames(mtcars), multiple = TRUE,
                     options = list(placeholder = 'None', onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')))
    ),
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "tableau"),
      br(),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "row_select"),
      uiOutput(outputId = "car_selected")
)
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$tableau <- renderUI({ 

  # here we add check box into the table: it create 6 new input widgets
  mtcars$choice = unlist(lapply(1:nrow(mtcars),
                                FUN = function(x) { paste(capture.output(checkboxInput(inputId = paste0("row", x),
                                                                                       label = paste("Row", x),
                                                                                       value = TRUE)), collapse = " ") }))

  tabl = FlexTable( mtcars,
                    # tune the header and the cells
                    header.cell.props = cellProperties( background.color = "#003366", padding = 5 ),
                    body.cell.props = cellProperties( padding = 5 ),
                    header.text.props = textBold( color = "white" ),
                    add.rownames = TRUE )

  tabl = setZebraStyle( tabl, odd = "#DDDDDD", even = "#FFFFFF" )

  # set a column's color
  if (input$colCol != "None") {
    tabl = setColumnsColors( tabl, j=which(names(mtcars) %in% input$colCol ), colors = "orange" )
  }

  # set a row's color
  if (!is.null(input$rowCol)) {
    tabl = setRowsColors( tabl, i=which(rownames(mtcars) %in% input$rowCol ), colors = "#3ADF00" )
  }

  return(HTML(as.html(tabl)))

})

output$row_select <- renderPrint({
  # you can use the input created into the table like others
  c("row1" = input$row1, "row2" = input$row2, "row3" = input$row3, "row4" = input$row4, "row5" = input$row5, "row6" = input$row6)
})

output$car_selected <- renderUI({
  # if you have more than 6 rows it could be convenient
  selected = eval(parse(text = paste("c(", paste(paste0("input$row", 1:6), collapse =", "), ")")))
  HTML(paste0("You have selected the following cars : ", paste(rownames(mtcars)[selected], collapse = ", ")))
    })
  }
))
```

Which render like this (with check box) :

[image]